# The use of articles

Tags: articles

"The statistics on rate of learning English are impressive."

I came across this sentence in a grammar textbook.

I do not understand why there is not a definite article before for "rate of learning English" since one of the rules for using a definite article is that the noun is restricted to a phrase/clause. In this case, I believe the noun "rate" is restricted by the phrase "of learning English" and the word "rate" is a countable noun, so, if I understand the rules correctly, it should be either in its plural form,"rates"; or with an article prior to the word itself, as in:

> "The statistics on rates of learning English are impressive"

Or

> "The statistics on *the* rate of learning English are impressive."

Am I understanding the rules correctly? Or all the 3 example s above are correct and carry similar meanings? Can someone elaborate? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sentence should use either the definite article or the plural form. The original source appears to simply have an error.

Answer (score 0):

When "rate of learning" is understood as a rubric, a category (e.g. of information), no article is needed.

> The investigators sought to quantify rate of learning.
>
> The QA Department keeps statistics on rate of failure.
>
> The ship's doctor will want to know in advance our intended depth of dive.
>
> A choreographer's diagram indicates direction of movement.
>
> A garbled announcement over the PA said something about a delay in time of departure.
>
> You cannot submit the shipping manifest without supplying weight of cargo.
>
> The graphic designer was experimenting with rate of saturation for the background color of the page.
>
> The CDC records rate of mortality for each viral outbreak.
>
> Once patients leave ICU the system then tracks [rate of mortality and length of stay](http://www.torontostandard.com/the-sprawl/the-future-of-our-city-health/).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I still have one more question though. Will adding an indefinite article alter the meaning?

Comment: @Tom Lee: The indefinite article would definitely change the meaning.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Tom Lee Please ask that as a separate question.